# Share icon not showing in ActionBar

Tags: android

I am trying to use ShareActionProvider as in http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html but my ActionBar does not show the share icon. Instead, the overflow button is shown which a menu item "share" (the rest works well). I am using this code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:title="share"
    compat:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
</menu>
```

In my activity, I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu resource file.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    // Return true to display menu
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// Call to update the share intent
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

And my theme is:

```
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Base">
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_back</item>
</style>
```

Why is does the share icon not show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your code (`compat:showAsAction`) is written to use the `appcompat-v7` backport of the action bar.

Some of your code (`getActionProvider()`, `Theme.Light`) is written to use the native action bar.

**Pick one and stick with it.**

My guess is that more of your current code is set up for the native action bar, in which case changing `compat:` to `android:` in your menu XML resource will probably get your `ShareActionProvider` working.

Comment: When I change to android: in my menu file, it tell me to use compat:showAsAction because I am using the appcompat library. I am wondering how I can chance this. I guess I don't need appcompat.

Comment: @tw-S: "it tell me to use compat:showAsAction because I am using the appcompat library" -- again, pick one and stick with it. "I guess I don't need appcompat" -- probably not. Here is a sample project that uses `ShareActionProvider` and does not use `appcompat-v7`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ShareNative

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. One question: How can I get rid of the Appcompat library references in my current project? It seems to stick around...

Comment: @tw-S: Simplest thing is to get rid of the library itself, then fix up any build errors. If you are using Android Studio, check your module's `build.gradle` file and remove the `appcompat-v7` line. If you are using Eclipse, choose Project > Properties from the main menu, choose Android in the properties dialog, and remove the `appcompat-v7` entry in the list of attached library projects.

Comment: Oh - I noticed your code in https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ShareNative doesn't work for me. The icon appears but there is no click response. I read that one needs to assign a default intent for the ShareActionProvider to work.

Comment: @tw-S: You need to type something into the `EditText`, at which point I set the `Intent` onto the `ShareActionProvider`.